# React select change the selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, formik

i am tying to build a multi select of items. my backend data structure is an array of objects like this

```
{
"selectedItems": [
      {"_id" : ""}
   ]
}
```

the problem with react-select is when i select one or many items, the structure does not match with my backend route, it displays like this

```
{
"selectedItems": [
      {"value" : "", label : ""}
   ]
}
```

i am working with Formik to manage the form and you can also see the result on this  [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-galois-cy8q4) on console log

```
const ItemSelected = () => {
    const items = [
        {
            _id : "123", name : "john", desc : 'eb'
        },
        {
            _id : "456", name : "doe", desc : 'ec'
        },
        {
            _id : "789", name : "seal", desc : 'ef'
        }
    ]

    const itemList = (options) => {
        return (
            options &&
            options.map(option => {
                return {
                    value: option._id,
                    label: option.name
                };
            })
        );
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    selectedItems  : []
                    }}

                onSubmit={values => {
                    console.log(values)
                }}
            >
                    {({
                          values,
                          handleSubmit,
                          setFieldValue

                      }) => (
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <Select
                                        isMulti
                                        name={`selectedItems`}
                                        value={values.selectedItems}
                                        onChange={e=>setFieldValue(`selectedItems`, e)}
                                        options={itemList(items)}
                                        className="basic-multi-select"
                                        classNamePrefix="select"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col">
                                    <button type="submit">
                                        submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to use map to create the data structure you want when you handle submit, just like you use map to create value and label options in React Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use map to create the data structure you want when you handle submit.

```js
onSubmit={values => {
  if(values.selectedItems){
    const data = values.selectedItems.map(value => ({_id: value.value}))
    console.log(data);
  }
}}
```